# Is it possible to make a page's publishing schedule mandatory?

Tags: publishing-page, schedule

As opposed to a page just being published as soon as it's approved - I need to make the schedule (the setting of the start and expiry date) of the publishing mandatory. Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint 2010 you can use List validation:

- Make sure your Page layouts include "Scheduling Start Date"
- Go to the Pages library
- Select List settings in the Library tab of the Ribbon
- Select Validation Settings
- Enter a formular like `=[Scheduling Start Date]>TODAY()`
- Enter an appropriate user message like "Page must be scheduled into the future"

As this probably needs to be done on multiple sites it could be a good idea to put it into a Feature which is included in/stapled onto the Site definition

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable versioning in the Pages Document library . More info on this [Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/schedule-the-start-and-end-date-for-a-published-page-HA010169330.aspx)